# Comparing Values from two JSON objects/arrays

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to compare 2 different JSON objects fetched from 2 different APIs. I've successfully fetched data from both of them into 2 variables now I need to setup a condition where my store inventory is same as my website's.

```
    $user = json_decode($response_store);
    $user2 = json_decode($response_woocommerce);

foreach($user->data as $mydata)
{
    foreach($user2->data as $mydata2)
    {

        if($mydata->CODE == $mydata2->sku)
        {
            echo $mydata->CODE;
        }
    }
}
```

So $user is returning products from store inventory and has a CODE attribute while $user2 is returning products from my Woocommerce store so I need to check if the CODE matches with SKU, it should also update the quantity according to my store inventory on my WooCommerce store.

P.S: Sorry for the long post. Tried to share as many details as I could. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would help to echo out the values to visually inspect if they are matching?  `echo "Does " . $mydata->CODE . " = " .  $mydata2->sku . " ?\n";`

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @Zak. Yes, but I want a different result rather than echoing these values. I would like to update the stock inventory of my Woocommerce based on the value from my store inventory. Each inventory also has an attribute named "quantity" in the array.

Comment: @Loko. As I said above, I need to match the value of stock on my website inventory with store inventory if there's a matching ID/SKU.